# Uploadify onComplete event

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I am using the excellent 'Uploadify' to handle multiple image uploads.

What I want to do is, once each image is uploaded, call a PHP script which performs a number of steps on each image (size manipulation and writing image details to MySQL database).

The question I have is how is this achieved? I reaslise that Uploadify has the OnComplete event, with the relevant parameters, but how do I call my PHP script each time an image is uploaded, and without navigating away from the current page (as other images may still be in progress)?

Comment: Aren't you invoking a PHP script that handles the upload process? Why don't you do the resizing / manipulation there instead of issuing 2 requests?

Comment: +1 from me @Michael J.V.

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys. Just realised this myself. The 'uploadify.php' file included is exactly the right place to do this. Doh! I'm off now to stand in the corner with a traffic cone on my head with a big D painted on it!

Comment: Can't see the forest because of the trees :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by other members, the included 'uploadify.php' file is exactly the right place to add any code you want to execute after an image had been uploaded.